# Is there anything in pc or registry that i need to activate to use uiautomation accessibility api

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, ui-automation, msdn, uiaccessibility

I developed an application that uses uiautomation api for accessibilty. I did initialize the element

```
   hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void**)&g_pAutomation7);
        if(!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {   
        }
```

and works fine on my pc. So, When i tried to test the application on another pc, the accessibility doesnt seem to work. So, when i opened inspect.exe to test the issue, as soon as i opened the inspect.exe, everything started to work. 
Is there anything that opening inspect.exe activated ?
Any help??